# Accessing APC Smart UPS Network Management Card via hostname

Tags: networking, dns, hostname, ups

I've got a new APC SmartUPS X 1500 with the build-in network management card AP9631, which I can access it via the ip-address `192.168.0.154`.

This IP-address has been given by my router's DHCP.

When I go to the following configuration screen in the Network Management Card:

> Configuration -> Network -> DNS -> Configuration

And set a host-name in that configuration window like this:

[image]

I can't seem to access it via my browser by typing in the following URL:

> http://MY-UPS-HOSTNAME/

It gave me this error: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

I've also tried to ping it, no success.

There is also no other device on this network with the same hostname.

**Question**

How can i access my UPS with the configured host name?

Answer (score 1):

Your router may manage this for you.  Assigning the UPS  a static IP on the router may add it to the lookup table on the router.

Add 192.168.0.1 as the primary DNS on the configuration page you have shown.

Failing that, you can edit the HOSTS file on your system

If Windows, the file is at  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ and you will need to assure that hidden files are displayed and then open the file in Notepad

To allow yourself to view all file types, open Windows Explorer  > Tools > Folder Options > View tab
 or Organize > Folder and search options > View tab 
•Scroll down to the Hidden Files and Folders section
•Select: "Show hidden files and folders"
•Uncheck: "Hide file extensions for known file types"
•Uncheck: " Hide protected operating system files"
•Ok the Prompt, click Apply, Ok

This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.

This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
 entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
 be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
 The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
 space.

Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
 lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.

For example:

```
  102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
   38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
```

localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost

You simply add a line with the IP of your UPS and then the name you wish to use

Save the modified file.

Note that this needs to be done for each computer on the network

Comment: Alright then... But why didn't this happen automaticly? Like we're used to i guess? I saved the configuration on the UPS right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Automatically.  The HOSTS file is a manual process.  Routers have different features.  More detail of what you have done may assist with a more detailed answer. Also, Based on the image, what happens when you uncheck Overrode manual?

Comment: Well, when i change the hostname on my router for example, and type that in into my browser's URL bar. I get to see the routers configuration window. (Reading the rest later, brb)

Comment: Since your router is handling name resolution for the network, it will respond to the name you assign it.  Devices on the network are handled slightly differently.

Comment: alright then, but what about PC's on the same network/domain? I can just type in the host name of a computer on the same network as me, and I get the file system of it. (If i do something like: `\\PC-PCNAME\c$\` in my windows explorer)

Comment: See the additional info in my original answer and try again

Comment: This didn't work, does this have to do something that the UPS is not connected to a router? It goes straight into my PC with an UTP cable.

Comment: The UPS has to be connected to the router I expect.  Test and see,

Comment: I'm afraid i dont have rights for this... :/ Isn't there another way?

Comment: Who manages the router? An IT department?

Comment: I'm the IT departement, but someone else controls the router, where i dont have the rights to

Comment: If you only want to access by name on your PC or a couple of PCs, then update the HOSTS file as indicated.   Not perfect but it will work